# How to undo a " " in c?

Tags: c

So Imagine that I am printingf something in the x=0 and y = 0 coordinates and now I want to printf something in the coordinate x=-1 and y = 0. How can I do it? Imagine that I printf " " and now I what to undo that " ", how can I do it?

Comment: Huh? Build the string you want to print before printing it. Jumping the cursor all over the place to overwrite something you've already printed is very platform-dependent and unreliable.

Comment: Well, don't do the `printf " "`! This is particularly easy by using `%2d` for the number

Comment: You generally can't. You can use trick, that works on some terminals - print `\r` to return cursor to the start of current line and then rewrite it. Example: `printf("ABC\rD");` will result in showing `DBC` on some terminals.

Comment: If you do not want to print: just don't print it.

Comment: Maybe explain what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Plain ISO C offers only very limited functionality of moving the text cursor on the screen. See the other answer for details on what it does offer.

However, most common operating systems provide their own additional functions that allow you to freely move the text cursor on the screen. For example, on Linux, you can use [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). On Micrsoft Windows, you can use the [Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/using-the-console), for example the function [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition).

Also, some operating systems support [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) that allow cursor positioning. For example, recent versions of Microsoft Windows support [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).

Comment: ISO C does have a notion of a screen/terminal/console, which it calls a display device. Per C 2018 5.2.2 2, printing the `\b` character is intended to move the active position to the previous position on the current line.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I was unaware of that. Thanks for pointing it out. I have reformulated my incorrect statement and am now referring to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have printed a partial line, so the active position on the display device is not at the beginning of a line, then printing the backspace character, `'\b'`, is intended to move the active position to the previous position on the current line, per C 2018 5.2.2 2.

Historically, this was not supported on all devices, but, assuming you have not resurrected a half-century old teletype, your display device will likely support this.

The C standard’s specifications of display manipulation are very limited. The behavior of `'\b'` when the active position is at the start of the line is unspecified, and nothing is provided to move the position to previous lines or to arbitrarily chosen locations in the display or to erase characters.